# How to send message in a thread using microsoft graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, email-threading

I'm building a tool in which I need to send more than 2 messages in the same thread (the message have identical subject & recipients) using Microsoft Graph API with some interval of days between them.

The problem is that I cannot send a message in the same thread using the API, even though the subject & recipients are same, Outlook displays them as different threads (but on the recipients' side (Gmail side) - they belong to same thread).

I tried using `conversationId` (which I got in the first message) in the second message but they still ended up showing in different threads.

Is there any way in I can send messages in the same thread?

Comment: how did you retrieve messageid/conversationid after you sent the message using /microsoft.graph.sendmail endpoint. As it doesnt return any response , i was curious how did you retrieve them

Comment: @zee This GitHub issue posted describes a way to do this by adding a custom identifier and then querying for it: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3766

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I assume you want to use the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/threads` endpoint to send more than 2 messages in the same thread.
 Refer to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_threads),

> A new conversation, conversation thread, and post are created in the group. Use reply thread or reply post to further post to that thread.

So we can use the [replay](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/conversationthread_reply) endpoint to send message in the same thread.

Comment: In my use-case, creating groups is not feasible and it actually voids one of the requirement.

Comment: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/microsoft.graph.sendmail` for sending mail. I thought if I add conversation-id or thread-id in the subsequent request then the mails will go in the same thread.

Comment: We can use the [replay endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_reply) to send message in the same thread

Comment: Actually, I did look up this API but I want to send some attachments too which is not possible according to documents.

Answer (score 1):

To send emails in one thread you should use [createReply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-createreply?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) method where you provide messageId of a previously sent message.

The tricky part is that after you sent a message with `send` or `sendMail` API methods, you do not have access to messageId. Even if you create a message via `create` method, messageId will be different after sending it.

So the solution is to send the message and find it in 'Sent Items' folder to retreive messageId. I am doing this based on time, subject and receiver. There is also useful param [$top](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters).

With correct messageId you'll be able to create reply and send it in the same thread.